# Using Rays for a bouncing projectile does not work with shallow angles

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject that bounces around the scene using a ray and the reflect transform. However, at sharp angles, the ray doesn't detect the wall before the object collides with it. If I extend the range of the ray then it will prematurely bounce off the wall. I want the object to move at a continuous constant speed like the ball in a pong game.

How do I detect shallow angled collisions and reflect the projectile off of them without extending the range of the ray

[image: Google Drawing of my problem]

Comment: The collision math between a circle and a square involves increasing the square's size by the radius of the circle and testing that against a point. You're doing the latter half and not the former. Also, why aren't you using the 2D physics engine that comes with Unity?

Comment: Use the Physics.CapsuleCast instead of RayCast.

Comment: @Draco18s I am new to unity and I have elements in the game that require a 3d environment. Unless you are suggesting there is a way to apply 2D physics to a 3D game.

Comment: Nothing stops you from using 2D physics where you need it and 3D physics where you need it. The two systems will literally glide through each other as they use and operate using completely different components and physics engine.